# Php encrypt,decrypt without special characters and digits length should be 6-8

Tags: php, encryption

In php I want to encrypt and decrypt data. I don't want to use special character. I only 6-8 digits with alphabets and numbers. For encrypt and decrypt I have made this function but sometimes it fails to decrypt the encrypted digit also its very length with special characters.

```
function random_password($length = 8) {
    $password = "";
    $possible = "2346789bcdfghjkmnpqrtvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRTVWXYZ";
    $maxlength = strlen($possible);
    if ($length > $maxlength) {
        $length = $maxlength;
    }

    $i = 0;

    while ($i < $length) {
        $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, $maxlength-1), 1);
        if (!strstr($password, $char)) {
            $password .= $char;
            $i++;
        }
    }

    return $password;
}

function encrypt($plaintext, $salt) {
    $td = mcrypt_module_open('cast-256', '', 'ecb', '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $salt, $iv);
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $plaintext);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    $encoded_64 = base64_encode($encrypted_data);
    return trim($encoded_64);
}

function decrypt($crypttext, $salt) {
    $decoded_64=base64_decode($crypttext);
    $td = mcrypt_module_open('cast-256', '', 'ecb', '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $salt, $iv);
    $decrypted_data = mdecrypt_generic($td, $decoded_64);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    return trim($decrypted_data);
}
```

Comment: I think the general advise in this question is going to be to **not** roll your own encryption. Sorry I can't be more helpful than that.

Comment: Start from the beginning: what's the use case for the encryption, what possible input will it accept, what is the output you want to produce and why?

Comment: 6-8 digits doesn't sound very secure.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @apokryfos While 6-8 digits isn't very secure" that may be all that is needed for the use case. We await for the OP to present the use case.

Comment: `CAST-256` is not a recommended algorithm, use AES. Also, ECB mode (not recommended) does not use an iv. $salt is a bad name for the encryption key. – zaph 5 mins ago    edit

Comment: @zaph I can't think of any use case where encryption is required but 6-8 digits are enough, since this also implies that the input can't be very big either so bruteforcing would be a realistic thing to do. If this isn't a concern I don't see the need to encrypt in the first place.

Comment: @apokryfos I can think of use cases. One would be to prevent the casual observer from knowing the plain text value. Believe it or not, not everyone is a programmer with cryptographic knowledge such that they can just whip out a program to decrypt something on a whim. All encryption is just increasing the work factor and this increases the work factor.

Answer (score 2):

I have two statements, and then *so many questions*.

1. That encryption code you wrote isn't secure, so don't use it. And please inform wherever you found that code that they're distributing insecure crypto code.

   - I mean, CAST-256 in ECB mode... with an IV? And using `MCRYPT_RAND`? And totally unauthenticated? No security expert would sign off on that.
2. Using `mt_rand()` in a function called `random_password()` is also concerning. You're not using a CSPRNG.

What exactly are you asking for?

> I don't want to use special character. I only 6-8 digits with alphabets and numbers.

So, you want the output size to be between 6-8 (why is this variable?) digits long, with only alphanumeric characters?

> `2346789bcdfghjkmnpqrtvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRTVWXYZ`

Why are there are no vowels?

What problem are you trying to solve here?

Why don't you just use [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) and use whatever password you want with it? Or eschew the password entirely and use its key-based encryption features (the default)?

I recommend going with a secure PHP encryption library rather than writing your own.

And please do inform your source of the security mistakes in their published crypto code. The less people use that code, the more secure the Internet becomes.

Comment: Perhaps Microsoft should also be informed, they are hosting sample code: ["How to encrypt and decrypt a file by using Visual C#"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307010) that uses DES.

Comment: @zaph I left a strongly worded "feedback" starting with a request to literally "nuke this from orbit" :P

Comment: Great! The problem is that old answers stay around and developers new to crypto can't tell what to use and very often pick up the worst as a base having no idea what is happening.